# Make supervisor stop Celery workers correctly

Tags: python, django-celery, supervisord, celery-task, django-supervisor

I meet a lot weird thing when using celery. Such as, I update tasks.py, `supervisorctl reload`(restart), but tasks is wrong. Some tasks seems disappear and so on.
Today I found that because `supervisorctl stop all` can not stop all celery workers. And only kill -9 'pgrep python' can kill them all.

situation:

```
    root@ubuntu12:/data/www/article_fetcher# supervisorctl
    celery_beat                      RUNNING    pid 29597, uptime 0:52:18
    celery_worker1                   RUNNING    pid 29556, uptime 0:52:20
    celery_worker2                   RUNNING    pid 29570, uptime 0:52:19
    celery_worker3                   RUNNING    pid 29557, uptime 0:52:20
    celery_worker4                   RUNNING    pid 29586, uptime 0:52:18
    uwsgi                            RUNNING    pid 29604, uptime 0:52:18
    supervisor> stop all
    celery_beat: stopped
    celery_worker2: stopped
    celery_worker4: stopped
    celery_worker3: stopped
    uwsgi: stopped
    celery_worker1: stopped
    supervisor> status
    celery_beat                      STOPPED    Aug 04 11:05 AM
    celery_worker1                   STOPPED    Aug 04 11:05 AM
    celery_worker2                   STOPPED    Aug 04 11:05 AM
    celery_worker3                   STOPPED    Aug 04 11:05 AM
    celery_worker4                   STOPPED    Aug 04 11:05 AM
    uwsgi                            STOPPED    Aug 04 11:05 AM
```

processes:

```
root@ubuntu12:~# ps -aux|grep 'python'
Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html
root      8683  0.0  0.1  61420 11768 ?        Ss   Aug03   0:27 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord
root     29310  0.1  0.1  57120 11344 pts/2    S+   11:05   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisorctl
nobody   29556  2.2  0.5 132484 45988 ?        S    11:06   0:00 /data/www/article_fetcher/venv/bin/python /data/www/article_fetcher/manage.py celery worker -n W1 -Ofair --app=celery_worker:app
nobody   29557  2.2  0.5 132480 45996 ?        S    11:06   0:00 /data/www/article_fetcher/venv/bin/python /data/www/article_fetcher/manage.py celery worker -n W3 -Ofair --app=celery_worker:app
nobody   29570  2.4  0.5 132740 45996 ?        S    11:06   0:00 /data/www/article_fetcher/venv/bin/python /data/www/article_fetcher/manage.py celery worker -n W2 -Ofair --app=celery_worker:app
nobody   29571 26.9  1.4 217688 115804 ?       R    11:06   0:09 /data/www/article_fetcher/venv/bin/python /data/www/article_fetcher/manage.py celery worker -n W3 -Ofair --app=celery_worker:app
nobody   29572 33.7  0.7 158396 59808 ?        R    11:06   0:12 /data/www/article_fetcher/venv/bin/python /data/www/article_fetcher/manage.py celery worker -n W3 -Ofair --app=celery_worker:app
nobody   29573 29.6  1.4 215176 115928 ?       R    11:06   0:10 /data/www/article_fetcher/venv/bin/python /data/www/article_fetcher/manage.py celery worker -n W1 -Ofair --app=celery_worker:app
nobody   29574 27.2  1.4 218244 118180 ?       R    11:06   0:09 /data/www/article_fetcher/venv/bin/python /data/www/article_fetcher/manage.py celery worker -n W3 -Ofair --app=celery_worker:app
......
......
......
```

I found this question:[Stopping Supervisor doesn't stop Celery workers](https://coderwall.com/p/4tcw7w/setting-supervisor-to-really-stop-django-runserver), but it is asking different thing, the accepted answer `supervisorctl stop all` do not work actually.So I decide find the right way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I look into [supervisor docs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=stopsignal#program-x-section-settings) and find this:

> killasgroup
>
> If true, when resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
>   send it to its whole process group instead, taking care of its
>   children as well, useful e.g with Python programs using
>   multiprocessing.
>
> Default: false
>
> Required: No.
>
> Introduced: 3.0a11

Then I think that each worker create 4 child process(by cpu cores) become a process group, that's why `supervisorctl stop all` do not work.
So I add `killasgroup` to supervisord.conf:

```
    [program:celery_worker1]
    ; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv

    directory=/data/www/article_fetcher

    command=/data/www/article_fetcher/venv/bin/python /data/www/article_fetcher/manage.py celery worker -n W2 -Ofair --app=celery_worker:app
    user=nobody
    numprocs=1
    stdout_logfile=/data/www/article_fetcher/logs/celery.log
    stderr_logfile=/data/www/article_fetcher/logs/celery.log
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    startsecs=5
    killasgroup=true

    .....
    .....
```

Then `supervisorctl stop all` really stop celery workers! very well~